# Synchronized on Servlet service method

Tags: java, servlets

I was reading the Servlet Specification and came across this:

> For servlets not implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, if the service
>   method (or methods such as doGet or doPost which are dispatched to the service
>   method of the HttpServlet abstract class) has been defined with the synchronized
>   keyword, the servlet container cannot use the instance pool approach, but must
>   serialize requests through it.

I don't understand why the servlet container cannot use the instance pool approach with a synchronized service method. Doesn't the instance pool contain different instances of the servelet so that every instance will use itself to synchronize the method (not blocking each other)?

From what I understand the the synchronize will be useless in this case but it does not stop the servlet container from using an instance pool.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What that sentence is saying is that if you dont implement `SingleThreadModel` then your Servlet instance wont be pooled at all **no matter it it uses `synchronization` or not**. The only reason it mentions `synchronization` is to **warn** you that Servlet container wont be using multiple instances of your Servlet per VM to allow it to process multiple requests at the same time.

Here is another missing fragment from the spec:

> SRV.2.2 Number of Instances
>
> The servlet declaration which is part of
>   the deployment descriptor of the Web application containing the
>   servlet, as described in Chapter SRV.13, “Deployment Descriptor”,
>   controls how the servlet container provides instances of the servlet.
>   **For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default),
>   the servlet container must use only one instance per servlet
>   declaration**. **However, for a servlet implementing the SingleThreadModel
>   interface, the servlet container may instantiate multiple instances to
>   handle a heavy request load and serialize requests to a particular
>   instance.** Servlet Life Cycle 19 In the case where a servlet was
>   deployed as part of an application marked in the deployment descriptor
>   as distributable, **a container may have only one instance per servlet
>   declaration per Java Virtual Machine (JVMTM)** 1 . **However, if the
>   servlet in a distributable application implements the
>   SingleThreadModel interface, the container may instantiate multiple
>   instances of that servlet in each JVM of the container**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand why the instance pool approach does not work regardless of the synchronization keyword like you mentioned. However, I don't see how mentioning the synchronization keyword warns that there will be only one instance used by the servlet container.

Comment: The sentence is indeed worded weirdly. It essentially says
1. If you don't implement SingleThreadModel there will only be one Servlet instance per JVM (as tsolakp pointed out);
2. If you make the method synchronized, requests will be processed serially by that one Servlet instance.
The combination of those two factors will degrade performance.